# any NATIVE tool how to see bandwidth of upload/download on PC in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, bandwidth

I need to see connection speed from linux PC (like 0.7MB/sec) but it is very secure machine and I'm afraid to install some 3rd party tool -> was looking everywhere but every tip for some sw was needed to apt install and it was not native -> is there any NATIVE or.. 10000000000% trusted tool you would use on top security machine to measure bandwidth? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are native tools that exist to check the bandwidth in Linux.

But if you want to monitor bandwidth usage per process you can use this command:

> `sudo watch -n1 netstat -tunap`

or use 3rd party tools such as `iftop` or `iptraf` for monitor the bandwidth and you can trust them.

> sudo iftop

> sudo iptraf-ng

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/` etc. together with a small script to do measurements in a loop with `sleep`, that will work without installing anything.

No, I don't have a script handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do it once (e.g. as a sanity check that the connection has roughly expected performance), you can do it "the old fashioned way":

Download/upload something (larger files are better) using whatever approved method already exists on the system, and measure the time taken by the upload/download. Then divide the size of the file transferred by the number of seconds it took. The result is the average speed of that specific transfer.

Comment: I need to check if one program is downloading and how fast :)